# need help catch a formatexception error

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, try-catch

My workaround solution seems silly but it prevents the error.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
try 
{
myNumber =  Convert.ToInt32(InputRow.Substring(288, 9));  
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
}
```

Comment: The way to fix this is to know what InputRow contains at location 288 - 297

Comment: int.TryParse(...) would probably be a little cleaner.

Comment: **DEBUG DEBUG DEBUG**. What is the value of this: `InputRow.Substring(288, 9)`? If it isn't a number.. your conversion will fail.

Comment: Simon during debug it is a number like this: 0x00001da1.   I don't know how to make it show as a "human" number unless I make it a string....BTW it correctly inserts as the correct number in the database.

Comment: @Doreen That isn't a valid number..

Comment: Simon I realize that but I don't know how to make it valid. The reason I'm stumped is because it inserts into database as the correct number.

Comment: You need to provide more information in your post. Update it with the string you're attempting to pluck the number from, what the expected number generated is, etc.

Comment: hogan - the input row at location 288,9 could be like this "0        0"  or like this "7      934".   Basically it contains, nothing, zero, or a number. The startIndex is positioned before the first digit in my example i.e. "288" is before 0 or 7 and spans 9 spaces.

Comment: If your number is really something like 0x0001da1, you probably want to interpret it as hexadecimal. In that case, try Int32.TryParse() with NumberStyles.HexNumber specified. You'll need to adjust your index to cut off the "0x" part though:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27.aspx

Comment: @OrenMelzer-MSFT That won't work.. it isn't a valid hexidecimal number (it will throw the same exception). You need to remove one of the leading zeros (e.g: `0x001da1` instead of `0x0001da1`)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Actually, that was just me transcribing the OP's number incorrectly. He has four zeros. Thats what I get for not copy/pasting.

Comment: @Simon - I provided more info in my post but jeremy Thompson edited most of it out. The app starts by reading an uploaded text file that is then saved to byte array then written to a text file. The text file is opened and read with streamreader then passed to string where it is passed again to a method as "InputRow". I bring in as string, but Convert.ToInt32 even though myNumber is already declared as Int32 (and not a string!). During debug its displaying the number as hexidecimal....

Answer (score 1):

int.TryParse could be a good choice

```
int val = 0;
if(int.TryParse(InputRow.Substring(288, 9), out val))
   // insert val into db
```

Comment: -1 since he's only going to use `TryParse` to create a different workaround.